# Return the index of the deselected item of a list box?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm aware of finding the index of the item selected but how would i go about finding the item that was deselected? I have a list box that has mutli select and checkbox option. When I deselect a item, I want to know the index of it.

Here's my code to get index of selected.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim lItem, indexNum As Long
For lItem = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then
        indexNum = lItem + 1
    End If
Next lItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim lItem, indexNum As Long
For lItem = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then
        indexNum = lItem + 1
    Else
        indexNum = lItem + 1
        deselected = indexNum
        MsgBox deselected
    End If
Next lItem
End Sub
```

If it is selected, it sums. Otherwise, it adds a new one but do the thing you want (In my case msgbox)

Remember to stop the code with a exit for if you only need the first deselected item. On my example I had a list with 5 items. If I selected all of them, nothing happened. If I then selected the first one, it would give me 2, 3, 4, and 5 on msgboxes

Comment: I need it to work on multi select and deselect, i want to check and uncheck items on listbox and put a "1" in the worksheet staying which items was clicked ect.

Comment: Replace my msgbox with whatever code you need it to execute when you deselect.

Comment: yes, but it only works on single select/deselect, as soon as i select another item on the list, its stuck on the first item index and not the one that was select or deselect.

Comment: Oh, so you need a memory. Like "How it was" and "How is it now"

Comment: yeah i need to check it and then put a 1 on A1 lets say for item 1, then when i come back and uncheck item 1 from listbox, the 1 in A1 will be gone, i need to be able to multi do this with multiply items.

Comment: what about the other items in the listbox? you should have explained all this  when you posted your question.

Comment: you should accept @pokemon_Man 's  answer because it solves the question that you posted. the additional stuff that you want is not part of the original question.